# Category tree in a laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am building a product catalogue.

I have following models: Product, Category. Each product can have many categories and each category as well.

Product model:

```
public function categories() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('Category');
}
```

Category model:

```
public function products() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
}
```

How can i make category tree without using 3rd party packages like Baum or Nested Sets (They seem too complicated for my task).

Something like that:

```
Category1
--subcategory (level1)
---subcategory (level2)
Category2
--subcategory (level1)
---subcategory (level2)
```

Each category has following fields in db:

```
id
title
parent_id
```

How can i set category depth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up without using any 3rd party packages. Used native Eloquent for that.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to implement a [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), you can do it using your database server (PostgreSQL, MySQL...) or implement it in code. For Laravel there are some package options to help you with this:

https://github.com/etrepat/baum

https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel4-nestedset